# onGetViewFactory only called once for multiple widgets

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have an appwidget which uses `ListView`. 
I have created a class that extends `RemoteViewsService`:

```
public class AppWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {
    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return (new AppWidgetListFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent));
    }
}
```

In my `AppWidgetProvider`, I call the following method for each instance of the widget (for each `appWidgetId`):

```
private static void fillInList(RemoteViews widget, Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    widget.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.appwidget_listview, intent);
}
```

The constructor of the `AppWidgetListFactory`

```
public AppWidgetListFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

    System.out.println("New TVAPWLF for: " + appWidgetId);
    trains = WidgetData.getInstance().widgetMap.get(appWidgetId);
}
```

Now the problem is, that the `fillInList` method gets called just as often as there are instances of the widget, but the `onGetViewFactory` method only gets called once. This results in all the widgets showing the same data.

How can I fix this?

Comment: could you add some more code? does it work if you make the `fillInList` method non static?

Comment: In my case intent.putExtra does work. Each instance I get the correct necessary widget id.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I haven't tested this myself, but looking at the source code for `RemoteViewsService.onBind()`, I believe you can not just vary the extras in your Intent in order for it to detect that a new call to your `onGetViewFactory()` method is needed since it uses the `Intent.filterEquals()` method for the comparison:

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data included in the intents.

I would suggest passing the information that you need (widget id?) through the Intent's data instead, maybe something like:

```
private static void fillInList(RemoteViews widget, Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppWidgetService.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("content", String.valueOf(appWidgetId), null));
    widget.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.appwidget_listview, intent);
}
```

and respectively on the receiving side:

```
public TreinVerkeerAppWidgetListFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    appWidgetId = Integer.valueOf(intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart());

    System.out.println("New TVAPWLF for: " + appWidgetId);
    trains = WidgetData.getInstance().widgetMap.get(appWidgetId);
}
```

Comment: @Joe can u please check how to do this in my code, actually i made the changes as u said but now it crashes. This is my code http://pastie.org/7063960 and this is the logcat http://pastie.org/7063968

Comment: @Anshuman I see a problem on line 36 on your first pastie: `String.valueOf(appWidgetIds)`. Here `appWidgetIds` is an array instead of a single integer and it produces an invalid URI in the intent (something like "[I@424b7d58" instead of "2"). Do you meant to write `String.valueOf(appWidgetIds[0])` instead?

Comment: @Joe Yep its working now. I have one more question. Is it possible to set background image to the app widget listView inside the code, instead of setting it in the xml file.

Comment: @Anshuman It would probably be best if you post a new question since that seems to be an unrelated problem. Make sure you do a search to see if anyone has asked/answered something similar first :)

Comment: Wow, this solution almost literally saved my weekend of paranoia and frustration, I have the similar problem here but now the case is closed :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400576/remoteviewfactory-ondatasetchanged-only-called-once-per-notifyappwidgetviewdat

Comment: But what if I need to send 3 arrays of strings for example?

Comment: Wow, such a good answer! Thank you. Your answer works, thumbs up for that!

Answer (score 3):

Based on the above description another trick you can do if you are setting intent extra other than string could be:

```
Random random = new Random();
intent.setType(String.valueOf(random.nextInt(1000)));
```

This will invoke a call to onGetViewFactory();

Comment: Yes, perfect! Works great.

Answer (score 0):

to invoke a call to onGetViewFactory ( recreate the widget )

```
val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView)
```

make sure the intent has different parameter that sent before