# onGetViewFactory() called only once

Tags: android, widget, remoteview

I have created Collection Widget and in which I need to updated data through API. Everything seems to work fine but ListView update call is executed only once. While debugging I found that **onGetViewFactory()** method is getting called only once.
I have searched for the problem and used the solution from below link
[onGetViewFactory only called once for multiple widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350287/ongetviewfactory-only-called-once-for-multiple-widgets?lq=1)

But it didn't work for me.

Comment: if it didnt help, post ur sample on github

Comment: @HeyAlex, Thanks man. its solved, issue is that i was not calling the notifyDataChange for ListItem and because of that Widget Manager was not calling the ViewFactorie's onDataSetChanged method.